# changing image on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="bullets"> 
  <ul id="intrebari"> 
    <li> <img src="images/bullet.png" class="li-icon"> <a href="#"> Frequently Asked Questions </ a> </ li> 
    <li> <img src="images/bullet.png" class="li-icon"> <a href="#"> custumer Support </ a> </ li> 
    <li> <img src="images/bullet.png" class="li-icon"> <a href="#"> custumer Login </ a> </ li> 
  </ ul> 
</ div>
```

Using Jquery I want to change the image of each individual `<li>` when mouse on it. 
So far i  manage this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#intrebari>li a').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('color: red')
        $('li > img').attr('src', 'images/bulletactive.png');
    });
});
```

But doing so it change the image on all `<li>`

I know it can be dune

Can someone help

Comment: can you show us your dom structre, img placed after anchor tag or before anchor tag

Comment: your closing tags are broken.  There shouldn't be a space there.

Comment: **Do not edit the source code to remove problems**. @JosephMarikle is right, your closing tags are wrong and the constructed DOM tree is wrong too.

Comment: Joseph Marikle-there is no space on my editor.

Comment: then fix the code in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$('li > img')` returns all the images that are children of `li` and `.attr()` is applied on all the selected images. There are various ways to do it.

Since your img is just before your anchor you can get it using `.prev()`

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#intrebari>li a').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('color: red')
        $(this).prev().attr('src', 'images/bulletactive.png');
    });
});
```

If your are going to insert any elements in between img and anchor it does not work. alternate solution would be

```
$(this).closest("li").children("img").attr('src', 'images/bulletactive.png');
```

Try closing your img tags like this `<img src="images/bullet.png" class="li-icon"/>`

Comment: Thank's for the quick response.But the image doesent change.What i want is the image to change from de default tu the image bulletactive.png

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

**HTML**

```
<div id="bullets"> 
  <ul id="intrebari"> 
      <li> <img src="http://placehold.it/20/20" class="li-icon" /> <a href="#"> Frequently Asked Questions </a> </li> 
      <li> <img src="http://placehold.it/20/20" class="li-icon" /> <a href="#"> custumer Support </a> </li> 
      <li> <img src="http://placehold.it/20/20" class="li-icon" /> <a href="#"> custumer Login </a> </li> 
  </ul> 
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#intrebari>li a').mouseover(function() {
    $(this)
    .parents('#intrebari')
    .find('a').css('color','black')
    .prev().attr('src','http://placehold.it/20/20')
    .end().end().end()
    .css('color','red').prev().attr('src','http://placehold.it/30/30');

 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Na7Nb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have applied this in my code and its working fine.

```
        $('li').mouseover(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

    // img over
        $img = $this.find('img').attr('src');               
        bg = $img.replace(/^url\(['"]?/,'').replace(/['"]?\)$/,'').replace(/^.*\/|\.[^.]*$/g, '');
        $url ="pathToYourImage\bullet.png"; 
        $this.find('img').attr('src', '');
        $this.find('img').attr('src','"+$url+"');
        });
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's changing the image on all list items because of the selector $('li > img'). You have to use it like this: $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src', 'images/bulletactive.png');

Just as an advice, this is more easy and fast with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Added jquery mouse leave event

```
$('#intrebari>li a').mouseover(function() { console.log('over')
            $(this).css('color','red')
            $(this).prev().attr('src', 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-left-128.png');
        });
    $('#intrebari>li a').mouseleave(function() { console.log('out')
            $(this).css('color', 'blue')
            $(this).prev().attr('src','https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-right-128.png');
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kapilgopinath/4937t/38/